# RubyMine doesn't recognize directory created by Paperclip gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, rubymine

I am using the Paperclip gem to upload images. When I upload an image, Paperclip uses its default upload location which is at `/public/system`. I can navigate to the directory on Mac OSX and see the uploaded image and plus the image is successfully displayed on web page. However, RubyMine does not show the directory or image:

[image]

Why doesn't RubyMine recognize the directory that Paperclip created?

Comment: Note :style refers to the styles hash e.g. :thumb, :normal in paperclip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to refresh the directory tree. The IDE probably doesn't know about the directory because you didn't create the directory in the IDE; another application created the directory.

Another possibility is that the public/system directory is in your gitignore file and RubyMine might ignore files that are in that. I'm not positive about that because I'm not that familiar with RubyMine.

Comment: Yes you are right. I added the directory to my .gitignore file. I didn't realize that Rubymine does not display files that are in .gitignore.